# Custom Sort on list from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a web service call and looping the results as follows:

```
$.each(v.outcomes, function (kk, vv) {

}
```

I would like to sort `v.outcomes` using `vv.name` using the order in an array as a template, ex:

```
var names=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
```

if `vv.name` is not found in the array it is to be placed underneath the ordered list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to loop through the source array, and place the items into a new sorted one:

```
var names=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");

var sorted = new Array(v.outcomes.length);

// keep track of the end index to place "unknown" items
var end = v.outcomes.length-1;

v.outcomes.forEach(function(item) {
    var position = names.indexOf(item.name);

    // add item to the appropriate position, otherwise place at the end
    if (position != -1)
        sorted[position] = item; 
    else
        sorted[end--] = item;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xFYm/4/)